# Webpack alias for url

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, axios

How to set up `url` dynamically in Vue.js app depending on the environment (dev or production)?

For example:

In development `axios.baseURL` need to be: `'http://localhost:85/app'`
but in production, it needs to be `'/app/'`.

My `axios` config:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:85/app',
    headers: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    }
});

export default instance;
```

How to setup web pack for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `webpack.DefinePlugin`: http://developmentnow.com/2016/07/13/webpack-injecting-server-urls/